# Mostrar el error al mandar un formulario

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

tengo un caso muy extraño en `sql server manager`

me an ordenado trabajar sobre una tabla que muestre todos los campos de usuarios de forma editable (que cada dato sea un `input`)

todo va bien pero cuando trato de agregar una quinta `columna` con `campos` de `formulario` no edita nada

y no me manda error ....
ya intente con `sqlsrv_error` para my `query`

> sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); y no me muestra nada

este es mi `formulario` :

---

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario ORDER BY Id_usuario ASC";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
   <form name='form_update' method='post' action='periodo_update.php'>
<?php
    while ($usuario = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo "<td>{$usuario['idusuario']}<input type='hidden' name='idusuario[$i]' value='{$usuario['idusuario']}' /></td>";
  echo "<td>$NoEmpleado</td>";
  echo "<td><img src='$foto'  width='56'></td>";
  echo "<td>$us_nombre_real</td>";

  //echo "<td>$ruta</td>";
  echo "<td>$puesto_descripcion</td>";


echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' onkeypress='return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(((event||window.event).which||(event||window.event).which)));' name='pago[$i]' value='{$usuario['pago']}' /></td>";

echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' onkeypress='return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(((event||window.event).which||(event||window.event).which)));' name='sueldos[$i]' value='{$usuario['sueldos']}' /></td>";

echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' onkeypress='return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(((event||window.event).which||(event||window.event).which)));' name='dias_trabajados[$i]' value='{$usuario['dias_trabajados']}' /></td>";

echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' onkeypress='return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(((event||window.event).which||(event||window.event).which)));' name='dias_adicionales[$i]' value='{$usuario['dias_adicionales']}' /></td>";

  echo '</tr>';
        ++$i;
    }
</tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>   
<td><input type='submit' value='Update' class='btn btn-info'/></td>
   </tr>
   </form>
------update

$size = count($_POST['pago']);
    $i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
    $pago1 = $_POST['pago'][$i];
    $sueldos1 = $_POST['sueldos'][$i];
    $dias_trabajados1 = $_POST['dias_trabajados'][$i];
    $dias_adicionales1 = $_POST['dias_adicionales'][$i];
    $idusuario = $_POST['idusuario'][$i];

    $query = "UPDATE usuario SET pago = '$pago1', sueldos = '$sueldos1', dias_trabajados ='$dias_trabajados1', dias_adicionales ='$dias_adicionales1'  WHERE idusuario = '$idusuario' ";



    sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
    //echo "$pago<br /><br /><em>Updated!</em><br /><br />";
    ++$i;
}
```

de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Ya revisaste que los campos de la base de datos cuenten con la misma cantidad de caracteres permitidos, que los caracteres que intentas introducir desde el formulario,también verifica que sean del mismo tipo de dato.

Comment: hola si, e revisado con distintos campos y checado las caracteristicas aun que aclaro que no tengo tanta experiencia con sql server , sigo sin entender por que si funciona en mis primeros 833 campos y luego deja de funcionar magicamente ya paso de no permitir la quinta columna a detenerse a la mitad D: